# Partially copy a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Hey I am really new to c and I have been sitting here for quite a while now trying to learn the most basic things about using structs.

I am now trying to copy a part of my struct into another so I can rearrange them as I see fit. This is what I have come up with thus far, I have altered the code several times trying to get this to work so I would really greatful if you could explain how I should alter the code and why.

What I have come up with so far is:

```
struct fruits {
  char name[20]
  int in_stock;
}

struct fruits temp, stock[] = {
  {"Apples", 10}
  {"Pears", 15}
  {"Bananas", 12}
}
```

From what I have understood thus far (I might very well be wrong) I have created two structs with the same content?

What I want do do now is simply switch place on the first and the third element (The 10 Apples with the 12 bananas)

And this is where I get stuck. 
I have tried a multitude of approaches

```
temp[1] = stock[1];
stock[1] = stock[3];
stock[j + 1] = temp[j];
```

or with memcpy

```
memcpy(&temp[1], &stock[1], sizeof(fruits));
memcpy(&stock[1], &stock[3], sizeof(fruits));
memcpy(&stock[3], &temp[1], sizeof(fruits));
```

Also tried to move single elements

```
memcpy(&temp[1].name, &stock[1].name, sizeof(fruits));
memcpy(&temp[1].in_stock, &stock[1].in_stock, sizeof(fruits));
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Comment: And what problems did you face? From what I can see it sems to be an issue with your indexing: `C` indexing starts from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @RoneyMichael from what I can see, the issue was a misunderstanding of how declarations work in C.  Seems like a legit beginner problem and I don't know why this question was moderated down to -2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
struct fruits temp, stock[] = {
    {"Apples", 10},
    {"Pears", 15},
    {"Bananas", 12},
};
```

This declares two variables.  The second one, `stock`, is an array of three structs; each of the three is of type `struct fruits`.  The first one, `temp`, is a struct of type `struct fruits`.

Thus, when you attempt to index `temp`, it doesn't work.

Here is a simple way to get two arrays of the same length.

```
#define FLEN 3  /* length of fruits array */

struct fruits stock[FLEN] = {
    {"Apples", 10},
    {"Pears", 15},
    {"Bananas", 12},
};
struct fruits temp[FLEN];
```

For `stock`, if you don't provide 3 values, the C compiler will warn you.  Then by re-using `FLEN` for `temp`, you get two arrays of the same length.

If you really want to init two arrays with the same stuff, I'd recommend this:

```
#define FRUIT_VALUES \
        {"Apples", 10}, \
        {"Pears", 15}, \
        {"Bananas", 12},

struct fruits stock[] = { FRUIT_VALUES };
struct fruits temp[] = { FRUIT_VALUES };
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are indexed starting at 0, so the first element of the array is element 0, and the third element is element 2. Also, `temp` is not an array, so don't use bracket notation with `temp`:

```
temp = stock[0];
stock[0] = stock[2];
stock[2] = temp;
```